# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password :YES) joomla install on windows 7 with web platform installer

Tags: mysql, joomla, mysql-error-1045

I was trying to install Joomla on my machine .. so i ran the microsoft web platform and choose joomla Mysql and other tools went well .. BUT joomla it self isn't installed giving the following error :

This product did not  install successfully: the database 'my_site_db' could not be created
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password :YES)

It asked me to enter a password for Joomla and the database in the last step of installation.
I think i had MySQL already installed.

UPDATE : I downloaded Joomla from the website and worked on it using XAMPP and the installed version from Joomla's website.

Answer (score 1):

You obviously have MySQL installed, because this message comes from MySQL server.
Make sure that the password you provided is the password for MySQL's root user.

Comment: i made sure i put the root's password .. even gave joomla's database the same password .. and still the same problem !

Comment: Check if user root@localhost indeed exists and has privileges.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using the root user for accessing a website. Root has access to everything.

Can you create a new user using phpMyAdmin or alternative? I'm not sure what tools come with the MS web platform, but you should create a user, with privileges to access the database and use that.

Comment: Fair point, although "Joomla on my machine" may mean that it is on a closed environment and so doesn't really matter

Comment: Complacency by software developers is what causes identify theft and worse for others later. Having a security mindset from the beginning is important.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can login with the root user on the MySQL Server (with a tool,..) , if not then re-setup the MySQL Server again. I've had this problem too for an unknown reason.

Answer (score 0):

Specify your windows user account as the root database password.  That worked for me.